# Key features - Pointcloud in ARcore

Tags: google-project-tango, arcore

Researching about Tango and ARCore I couldn't find out which algorithm is used for the key extraction. Reading the patent from Tango I suppose that they are using FREAK ( Fast Retina Keypoint) but is not clear.

Anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, ARCore uses SLAM (Simultaneous Localisation and Mapping). It basically does the below steps:

1. Figures the feature points with some image processing techniques for every frame
2. Compares them with the phone's displacement and the feature points from the previous frame.

Say.. if the feature points move a lot, then they are close to the camera. If the displacement is less, then they are farther away from the camera. That's how the depth is perceived!

Comment: Doesn't the displacement of the feature points become smaller when the point is further away?

Comment: Nope, it's the opposite. Try to imagine! Can't really explain it 

Comment: I think you're mistaken and this article explains it pretty well (scroll down to the depth vs disparity part) https://www.raywenderlich.com/168312/image-depth-maps-tutorial-ios-getting-started Besides, if you close one eye and than the other, you can easily observe that objects further away "jump" less than objects close by.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, you are right! If we close one eye, the one infront of us can move out of the view faster than the one farther so the displacement in the 2D plane should also be more! Please edit the answer if you would like to, or I will be happy to do it myself too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the "Point Cloud" behavior will be the same on ArCore as it is on Tango, simply because Tango devices have that infra-red sensor integrated in the camera. Sensing depth with a normal phone camera is not as powerful as the depth obtained with infra-red. As far as I know ArCore and ArKit are using Kalman filters to obtain simulated depth perception.